How far is the spectral norm from the Frobenius norm?
I know spectral norm is the smaller than any other norm. But can we qualify how small?
Formally, for a matrix $A$, what is $||A||_F - ||A||_2$ bounded by?
If it is not bounded, can the difference be arbitrarily large?

If $A = aI_n$ ($a$ times the $n \times n$ identity matrix), then $|A|_F-|A|_2 = |a|\sqrt{n}-|a| = |a|(\sqrt{n}-1)$. This can get arbitrarily big as $|a| \to \infty$ or $n \to \infty$ (as long as $a \neq 0$ and $n > 1$ of course).

If $A = aI_n$ ($a$ times the $n \times n$ identity matrix), then $$\|A\|_F-\|A\|_2 = |a|\sqrt{n}-|a| = |a|(\sqrt{n}-1).$$ This can get arbitrarily big as $|a| \to \infty$ or $n \to \infty$ (as long as $a \neq 0$ and $n > 1$).
However, you can obtain multiplicative relations between them. If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ has rank $r$ and non-zero singular values $\sigma_1 \ge \cdots \ge \sigma_r > 0$, then $\|A\|_2 = \sigma_1$ and $\|A\|_F = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{r}\sigma_i^2\right)^{1/2}$. From this, we can show that $$\|A\|_2 = \sigma_1 = (\sigma_1^2)^{1/2} \le \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{r}\sigma_i^2\right)^{1/2} = \|A\|_F$$ and $$\|A\|_F = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{r}\sigma_i^2\right)^{1/2} \le \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{r}\sigma_1^2\right)^{1/2} = (r\sigma_1^2)^{1/2} = \sqrt{r}\sigma_1 = \sqrt{r}\|A\|_2.$$ Hence, $$\|A\|_2 \le \|A\|_F \le \sqrt{r}\|A\|_2.$$
